# clang++, boost::spirit and c++11

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, boost-spirit, clang++

I'm using clang++ (clang-421.0.60), packaged with Xcode 4.6, and came across an issue with boost::spirit. If I compile without any flags, everything compile fine. If I compile with '-std=c++11', then I get the following error (on including of "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"):

```
In file included from test_spirit11.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:21:
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/support/action_dispatch.hpp:21:10: fatal error: 
  'type_traits' file not found

#include <type_traits>
```

The problem is that the default library used (stdlibc++) has type_traits defined as 'tr1/type_traits', whereas boost::spirit expects just 'type_traits'. I can of course fix this problem by doing:

```
 clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ <...>
```

While I would love to use libc++, the practicality of doing so is difficult (many libraries still use and depend on stdlibc++). Thus, I am forced to not use libc++.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with this? I really wish that either more library maintainers support libc++ or that Apple provided a newer version of stdlibc++. It's been a major frustration to have access to new c++11 features, but not be able to fully use them due to lack of library support.

Comment: As a stopgap measure, you could try adding `-I/path/to/stdlibc++/includes/tr1` to your compiler flags.

Comment: @n.m. that still won't work, the TR1 header puts the traits in namespace `std::tr1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that the default library used (stdlibc++)

It's called libstdc++

> has type_traits defined as 'tr1/type_traits', whereas boost::spirit expects just 'type_traits'.

`<tr1/type_traits>` is not the same thing, it's a different header entirely. `boost::spirit` wants the C++11 header `<type_traits>` which is a different header (though they do contain some similar functionality, in different namespaces.)

The problem is probably that you're using the libstdc++ that comes with Apple's ancient version of GCC (4.2) which doesn't support C++11.

If you want to use C++11 you either need to use clang with libc++ or install a newer GCC to get a newer libstdc++.  Apple won't provide a newer GCC for licensing reasons, but you can install it yourself and tell Xcode how to find the headers and libs.

Comment: Okay. That's good to know. Do you have any pointers for installing newer versions of the GCC libs?

Comment: You can't just install the newer libs, you need to install GCC itself. Either get it from some packager such as Macports or build it yourself following the instruction at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC (see the really simple script at the bottom of the page, **do not** manually install gmp, mpfr and mpc)

Comment: Just for the record, I went the homebrew route, which seems to work (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38222/how-do-i-install-gcc-via-homebrew).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use C++11 features in boost you can disable it.
Edit boost clang.hpp to manage features.
For example  to disable `type_traits` file not found error you can add to the end:

```
#define BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES
```